# Use two datasets of one collection in Meteor

Tags: meteor

The problem is that i need two different data sets of one mongodb collection

```
//lib/col.js
Photos = new Meteor.Collection("photos");
lastPhotos = function() {
  return Photos.find({},{sort:{created_time:-1},limit:4});
}
locationPhotos = function(location_id_var) 
{
    //**doesn't return data from server, goes to local cache**
    return Photos.find({location_id: location_id_var});
}
//server
Meteor.publish("lastPhoto", function () 
{
   return lastPhoto();
});

Meteor.publish("locationPhoto", function (location_id) 
{
   return locationPhoto(location_id);
});

//client
Meteor.subscribe("lastPhoto");
Meteor.subscribe("locationPhoto",{location_id:Session.get("location_id")});
```

The main problem that meteor merges two data sets of one collection.

At the templates I have two different presentations of one collection. Collection is big (6000 documents) and I can not send it to client wholly.

How can I get two different sets of documents of one collection without sending all documents to client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need to wrap your `subscribe` in an `autorun` to have it dynamically *change* the server's `publish` method.

I hope this is helpful:

Javascript:

```
var Photos = new Meteor.Collection("Photos");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Template.main.photos = function () {
    return Photos.find({location_id: Session.get("location") });
  };

  Meteor.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe("photos", Session.get("location"));
  });

  Template.main.events({
    'click button' : function (e) {
        Session.set("location", $(e.target).data("locale"));
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("photos", function(location_id) {
    return Photos.find({location_id: location_id}, {sort: { created_time: -1 }, limit: 4});
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
    {{#each photos}}
        {{location_id}} | {{created_time}} | {{name}} <br/>
     {{/each}}

    <hr/>

    <button type="button" data-locale="MSP">MSP</button>
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" data-locale="SEA">SEA</button>

</template
```